# What is this component: 48-27SD50020222?

Tags: identification, components

I was digging through my things and found this component (`48-27SD50020222`) but am not sure what it is.

I've tried searching for variations of the number `48-27SD`, `48-27SD500`, `27SD500`, etc. but no luck.

Would any of you know?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Integrated IR receiver/demodulator.

Comment: the 48-27SD50020222 is probably the board part number

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The comments are correct. That is an IR receiver. It can be used for decoding IR signals from IR transmitters, such as a typical TV remote. And if I'm correct, if it is paired with an IR transmitter, it can be used for short-range distance detection.

You can buy them from any standard online electronics store:
[sparkfun.com](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/10266)
[digikey.com](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/filter/optical-sensors-photo-detectors-remote-receiver/541?s=N4IgTCBcDaIJICUAEAnApgYwJZoG5pRAF0BfIA)
[adafruit.com](https://www.adafruit.com/product/157)